# Toyota Camry 1998 4 cylinder manual transmission

Tags: toyota, clutch, manual-transmission, camry

While in motion on 1st gear, despite clutch been pressed in full to shift on 2nd gear, the vehicle jerks even though its clutch not being released.  Predominantly vehicle is jerking on 2nd gear whereas all subsequent gears are falling smoothly & the motion is also normal.

What could be the fault for this jerks especially of 2nd gear, please advice.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

The only reason it would be jerking is if there is still power going through the clutch to the transmission. The reason it might be doing this is because of clutch hydraulics. More than likely either the master or slave cylinder is failing, or you have air in your hydraulic lines. The possible reason why you'd only be feeling this in 2nd is because more torque can be transmitted through 2nd gear. As you get higher in speed/gears, the clutch will slip enough you wouldn't feel it. Don't get me wrong, the clutch is most likely still slipping, it's just not completely released.

Check to ensure your clutch reservoir is up to full. Also check to see if there is any leaking at the master/slave cylinders. One other thing to check is to see if the hydraulic hose has any bulges in it.